# Must declare scalar variable - again

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datagrid control that I am trying to populate based upon a sql query with parameters entered on the page. I keep getting the 'must declare the scalar variable @epa1, so I'm kind of lost as to where to go. The VB code is:

```
     Dim DT As DataTable
    Dim DS As New DataSet()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=azda-sql1a;Initial Catalog=pesticide;User ID=sa;Password=Sql@dm!n")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim query As String
    Dim DA As SqlDataAdapter
    query = "select epa1, epa2, dist_nr as epa3, ai1, rei, rup from products where epa1 = @epa1 and epa2 = @epa2 and dist_nr = @epa3"

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epa1", txtEPA1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epa2", txtEPA2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epa3", txtEPA3.Text)
    '\search for pesticides based on epa numbers
    'select BrandName,ActiveIngredient1 from NewProductsList where epa1=# and epa2=# and epa3=#
    If Me.txtEPA1.Text = "" Or Me.txtEPA2.Text = "" Or Me.txtEPA3.Text = "" Then
        Me.lblProductErrors.Text = "Please enter in all EPA numbers for accurate search, when in doubt enter Zero"
    End If
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    DA = New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)

    DA.Fill(DS)
    DT = DS.Tables(0)
    conn.Close()
```

So I am assuming the all 3 variables, @epa1, @epa2, and @epa3 are not getting declared, but then again, there they are. Can anyone assist? Thanks..have have a good Christmas everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You set the parameters on your `Command`, yet you use `query` (without the parameters) to initialize your `DataAdapter`.

Thus, instead of initializing your DataAdapter with the query:

```
DA = New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
```

initialize it with the Command (which already has the parameters set):

```
DA = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
```